# Add menus into Roles in abp.io framework

Tags: menu, roles, abp

I have customize homepage in abp.io framework project with side menus. Now I want to add these menus into Roles. How can I add menus into roles ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set which permission/role is required before adding it to MenuConfigurationContext.

See https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.Identity.Web/Navigation/AbpIdentityWebMainMenuContributor.cs#L19